# Is there a way to send an HTML template through nodemailer to appear in the mail?

Tags: html, node.js, nodemailer

I'm trying to organize a template for the mail I'm trying to send to my email using MERN stack and nodemailer. This is kind of what I want to send as the response:

```
const {name, email, phone, message} = req.body;

    const mailOptions = {
        from: process.env.AUTH_EMAIL,
        to: 'vs61@queensu.ca',
        subject: 'Community Partnership Project Contact Form Inquiry',
        html: <div>Name: {name}<br/>Email: {email}<br/>Phone: {phone}<br/>Message: {message}</div>
    }
```

Except for the fact that this doesn't work. The backend crashes when I do it, this is the crash log:

```
      html: <div>Name: {name}<br/>Email: {email}<br/>Phone: {phone}<br/>Message: {message}</div>
              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I'm not sure how to send html code, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you explain what "this doesn't work" means? Any error messages? Broken content in email?

Comment: I updated the code, i added the crash log

Comment: Strings in JS must be quoted. Voting to close as ‘caused by typo’

Comment: you need to add single quotes '<>' and i believe double brackets {{}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set the email template in nodemailer but your syntax is wrong.

```
const name ='abc',email='abc@yopmail.com',phone='1234',message='hello there'
    const mailOptions = {
        from: process.env.AUTH_EMAIL,
        to: 'vs61@queensu.ca',
        subject: 'Community Partnership Project Contact Form Inquiry',
        html: `<div><p>Name: ${name}</p><br/><p>Email: ${email}</p><br/><p>Phone: ${phone}</p><br/><p>Message: ${message}</p></div>`
    }
```

> Note:'You forgot to add template literal and ${} so you can add dynamic values.'